# Bootstrap 4 navbar not collapsing or expanding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on teaching myself web development, and I thought what a better way than to start my own personal web page.

I have run into an issue working with Bootstrap 4 and the navbar.

I can get the list, and the icon to show up when the window shrinks, but I can't get it to expand, or toggle collapse. I've even copied and pasted some code from the bootstrap documentation to see what I'm doing wrong and even then it doesn't work.

I've tried on both firefox and chrome, and on both, I am still unable to toggle the collapse with the icon button.

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Heath's Personal Website">
  <meta name="keywords" content="heath, blandford, heath blandford">
  <meta name="author" content="heath blandford">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <!--import bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- import google fonts lobster and open sans -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">navbar</a>
  <!-- Navbar brand yo -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTop" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTop">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Services</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#social">Social Media</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although you've imported the Bootstrap CSS, you've neglected to import the required JavaScript.

Importing Bootstrap's JavaScript and the required dependencies (**[jQuery](https://jquery.com)** and **[Popper.JS](https://popper.js.org)**) will cause your navigation to toggle correctly.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Heath's Personal Website">
  <meta name="keywords" content="heath, blandford, heath blandford">
  <meta name="author" content="heath blandford">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--import bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- import google fonts lobster and open sans -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">navbar</a>
  <!-- Navbar brand yo -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTop" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTop">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Services</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#social">Social Media</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have known to include js. Doh!

Comment: yeah for me popper.js, and make sure you load bootstrap.js after jquery and popper